# Java/Flex ORM/DTO Generation Tool

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, orm, dto

Is there a tool out there that I can point at a Java DTO (Data Transfer Object) and it generates a corresponding Flex/AS Domain Object? Vise-Versa?

I'm using BlazeDS for my DataService over an AMF line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granite Data Services has a tool called GAS which will generate the DTO's for you:

http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/2.+Gas3+Code+Generator

Comment: I have heard some one tell me about this before.  I just could not find it on google for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this AIR app for blazeDS

http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/blazemonster/

Comment: I took a look at this and it looks great, but it doesn't work connections over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually write code to map Java DTO to AS classes, but there is no tool as such that is robust.